# Angular 2 - Disable form control based on the value of another form control

Tags: html, angular

I need help in disabling the value of a specific form control based on its value in Angular 2.

The field - **startDate** needs to be disabled whenever the value of another field - **period** is **"Lifetime"**. It needs to be enabled otherwise. Also, whenever the app is loaded, the default value of **period** is "**Lifetime**" so the **startDate** is disabled when the form is loaded.

So this is the code that I have written till now in my component:

```
protected onMetadataLoaded() {
const startDateControl = this.metadata.form.controls.startDate;
startDateControl.disable();
const periodControl = this.metadata.form.controls.period;
periodControl.valueChanges
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .subscribe(period => {
        if(period !== "Lifetime") {
            startDateControl.enable();
        } else {
            startDateControl.disable();
        }
    });

}
```

This allows me to enable the startDateControl when I change the period value from **Lifetime** to any other value. However, if I select the period value as **Lifetime** again, the startDateControl doesn't get disabled.

I'm guessing that it's checking it only once since I'm putting the code inside MetadataLoaded(). I'm not sure as to how I need to go about it so that it keeps monitoring the periodControl for value changes and enables and disables the startDateControl based on the period value.

Just for completeness: Period field has the following values - Monthly, Quarterly, Yearly, Lifetime.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

So this is what my template looks like:

```
<dynamic-form-item name="storeID" [metadata] = "metadata" type="chooser"></dynamic-form-item>
<dynamic-form-item name="period" [metadata] = "metadata"></dynamic-form-item>
<dynamic-form-item name="startDate" [metadata] = "metadata"></dynamic-form-item>
```

Basically a bunch of dynamic form items.

Comment: Could you briefly show what your template looks like?

Comment: Please create a demo to showcase this issue. Also this code is not enough to reproduce the issue :)